# Does React application work in Yandex Browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, cross-browser, yandex

I'm working on cross-browser compatibility issues. My react app works fine in most browsers, except in IE11 and Yandex. I have some errors shown in Yandex console, but I don't know where the error is pointing to.

This is what the error looks like.

[image]

Comment: It works in Yandex & IE11 browsers by installing and adding react app polyfills and core-js dependencies in index.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in Yandex & IE11 browsers by installing and adding react app polyfills and core-js dependencies in index.js file.